# Characterization and scope of claims in technology patents

Tags: patent-infringement, claims, technology

When viewing technology patents, I notice that they list a number of claims, and the structure of these claims takes various forms. Relating to this, my questions are as follows:

1. Does the scope of the patent pertain to what is described in each *individual* claim, or does the patent only apply to the technology described when considering *all* of the claims *in combination*?
2. When a claim outlines *steps*, does that mean that the technology in *each* of those *individual* steps is patented, or does it mean that the technology outlined/described by each of the steps *in totality* is patented?
3. When a patent claim outlines/describes a *system* consisting of *multiple parts*, are *each* of those *individual* parts under the scope of the patent, or is it only the *entire* system considered *in totality* that is considered to be under the scope of the patent?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify these points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very basic patent information that is duplicated in many previous answers.

1. Each claim stands alone as something that defines a device, system or method that would constitute infringement. A product might infringe one or more claims of a patent. Infringing one claim is infringing the patent.
2. To infringe a claim a product must contain all of the elements of that claim. In a method claim that would mean performing all of the steps. In a system claim it would require possess all elements with those elements related to each other as defined in the claim.
3. A claim can be written to encompass a whole system; other claims can be written to sub-components of that system. However to be granted, each claim must define something patentable - that is, something useful, novel and non-obvious.

"Technology" patents are mentioned in the question. That is not a specific category in U.S. patent law. We have three kinds of patents - *Utility* (a normal patent with one or more claims to something with utility) *Design* (With a single claim to the ornamental characteristics of a product) and *Plant* (covers new plants created from non-reproductive cells of the plant).

Re: "technology patent" - the answer is the same for all utility patents whether or not you would view them as involving technology. By the way, in much of the world a patent must be a technological solution to a technological problem. That is not true in the U.S. - we can patent a novel device for amusement that spins around, or a physically novel game piece/board, for example

Comment: By "technology patent", I meant the subset of utility patents that involve technology specifically.

Comment: My point was that the answer is the same for all utility patents whether or not you would view them as involving technology. By the way, in much of the world a patent must be a technological solution to a technological problem. That is not true in the U.S. - we can patent a novel device for amusement that spins around, for example

Comment: This basic question gets asked a lot on this site. This is one of the best answers.